# Depending on unreleased versions of packages

Tags: ros, buildfarm, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suppose I have a package A that has been released using bloom, and I am developing a package B that depends on A. Then, I add new functionality to A, and B makes use of this new functionality. If I release A but it has not made it to the public Debian repository yet, will package B successfully build on the build farm?

That is, does the build farm build packages by getting dependencies from the public repository? Or does it get the latest released versions of the dependencies?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262561/depending-on-unreleased-versions-of-packages/) by [justinhuang](https://answers.ros.org/users/21672/justinhuang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-05-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. The build farm uses the latest released version of a package when building binaries.

"dev" and "pr" jobs, however, will pull from the testing repository I believe, which will be more up-to-date than "public" but still will lag slightly behind the repository the build farm uses for binaries.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer, yes, it will work.

Slightly longer answer:

- Immediately after the binary job of A for a specific platform had finished successfully the binary job of B will run and use the Debian packages created by the other job.
- For the devel job of package B the all the binary jobs for that platform have to have finished (and no major regression has occurred). That is usually the case within the day.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-05-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1